# Disable all shortcut keys except 1

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-12.10

We have chromium running in kiosk mode. We would like to disable all the shortcut keys except one. With this one key we can quit the kiosk mode.

So we are searching for a way to disable all shortcut keys by script (except 1) and later when we quit the kiosk mode all the shortcuts should be active again. Any ideas how to fix this in Linux Ubuntu?